# When is the real Abel-Jacobi-Albanese map injective?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

$
\def\tMA{\tilde{M}_a}
\def\tomega{\tilde{\omega}}
\def\tx{{\tilde{x}}}
\def\tzeta{\tilde{\zeta}}
\def\T{{\mathbb T}}
\def\R{{\mathbb R}}
\def\Z{{\mathbb Z}}
\def\raw{\rightarrow}
$

I want to work strictly in the differential, real category, no complex structures.
Here is a standard definition of what is sometimes called the
Abel-Jacobi-Albanese map.

For simplicity,
let $M$ be a smooth,
connected, orientable, compact manifold
with $H_1(M;\Z) = \Z^b $ torsion-free.
Let $\tMA$ be its universal Abelian cover.
Pick a basis $\Gamma_1, \dots, \Gamma_b$ for $H_1(M;\Z)$ and
a basis generated by the closed one-forms $\omega, \dots, \omega_b$ for
$H^1_{DR}(M; \R)$ which
are dual in the sense that
$$
\omega_i(\Gamma_j) = \delta_{ij}
$$
(Kronecker delta). Lift the $\omega_i$ to $\tMA$ as $\tomega_i$
and fix a point $\tx_0\in\tMA$. For $\tx\in\tMA$
choose a  smooth path $\gamma$ from $\tx_0$ to $\tx$ and for
$i = 1, \dots, b$ define $\tzeta_i:\tMA\raw\R$ by
\begin{equation}
\tzeta_i(\tx) = \int_{\gamma} \tomega_i.
\end{equation}
Since the forms are closed, this is independent of the choice
of path $\gamma$. It is clear that $\tzeta$ is continuous and
descends to a map $\zeta:M\raw \T^b$.

Questions

1. For compact surfaces of negative genus it is classical that for the basis
   chosen from a special class of
   one-forms the map $\zeta$ is injective and thus a homeomorphism onto its
   image. Is this also
   true for any choice of the basis of $H^1_{DR}(M; \R)$?
2. When $M=\T^b$ is a torus to start with, I can chose the basis for
   which $\zeta$ is a homeomorphism $\T^b\raw \T^b$. If I chose another basis of
   $H^1_{DR}(M; \R)$, is it still a homeomorphism?
3. In general, what do I need to know about $M$ to say there is some
   basis for which $\zeta$ is injective? Also, are there cases where one basis
   works and another doen't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential of your real Abel-Jacobi map at $p\in M$ is given by $(\omega_1(p),\dots,\omega_b(p)).$ You can always change the $\omega_k$, $k=1,\dots,b$ on a given open ball $U\subset M$ by adding the differential of globally defined functions $f_k$ such that $\omega_k+df_k$ vanishes identically on $U$ for all $1,\dots,k$. This gives you a new Abel-Jacobi map, which is just constant on $U$, answering questions 1,2 and the second part of 3. For the first part of question 3, I don't know a general sufficient condition on $M$. Obviously, a necessary condition is  $b\geq\text{dim}(M).$